# Using raspberry pi as an alternative server

Tags: linux

I have an i5 with a gold(80) 700 watt power supply. I run a virtualbox with about 4 vms. Running a plex media server, web server, database, git, etc. Most of the time my server runs idle since its just me who really uses it.

I was thinking of using the new raspberry pi2 and getting 4 of them. I'm not to concerned about load issues since its my personal stuff.

What I'm wondering about since my current box has a 700 watt power supply and power consumption about 60 watts idle if running 4 raspberry pi's would be more energy efficient. My hard drives would be connect via usb so I wouldnt need to any external power supply.

Comment: It would use less power, yes. However, powering hard drives purely via USB requires powerful USB power supplies. Also, there’s the performance: If Plex needs to transcode videos, the Pi will most likely run out of juice. I also don’t see why you would need that many (virtual) machines.

Comment: Thanks.  I created different vms because I was building each seperately so if I messed up the VM I didnt screw up what I already have.  I only allocated 1gig of ram for each (having 16 gigs total).

Comment: Raspberry PI2 requires 5v 2A and the chances are your USB power output will not be enough. It's more down to your motherboard than the PSU - Does your motherboard have a USB charge utility that ups the ampage? It may work if the utility covers 4 ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I've got my hands on a "RPI B" only once and for very short time so am unable to give direct feedback with it.

BUT

I'm a **very satisfied** owner of an [OrangePI Plus](http://www.orangepi.org/) that is a similar "board" (as of physical dimensions and price-tags) but with some more hardware/interfaces and, as far as I can see from related SPECS, a slightly powerful CPU.

As for usage, there are some factors to keep into account when choosing/deciding **if** it will suite your needs:

- **using it as a network-server**: I'm referring about using such board remotely, accessing it via SSH or WEB, or other "server-like" usage (hosting GIT repositories, WEB server, DB server, etc.). Everything **not** involving the graphical desktop. 
  In such scenarios it works **perfectly**!
  I've been able to install on it the full gcc development stack to compile kernel modules, libraries and lots of other stuff! It all worked great and smoothly without even get the four CPU cores to 100%!
  Actually, after spending several hours connected to it via SSH from my main desktop computer.... I had even "forgotted" that it's a 40_€_class_hardware. It looked really "normal".
  So, **YES**, in my opinion you can use it to lower the power consumpion of your network-based IT services.
- **use it as a full desktop**: I also tried to connect a keyboard, a mouse, an HDMI monitor to it, so to use it as "common" desktop. As, from my background, I had a clear idea about the impact that graphic environments like recent versions of GNOME or KDE have on the underlying hardware, I went straight with a "light" desktop environment (an Ubuntu with LXDE).
  It still was a "usable" seat, but.... below any "common" threshold defined by "common" users expecting "common" performance from "common" current hardware platforms.
  In other words: I don't reccommend using it as a device directly connected to your 42" HDMI TV to play your preferred full-HD videos, stored on some HD directly connected to the PI+.... **unless** you know what you're doing and **unless** you have plenty (...plenty) of time to deal with fine-tuning.

This last point led me to the third important concepts you need to know, before entering the single-board computing world:

- **knowledge base / documentation are critical**: when I decided to try the graphical environment I quickly realized that the OS-image (Ubuntu-like) I was using had **no** accelerated graphic driver and cames builtin with the  common FBVESA X.org driver, which for sure were unable to grant proper 3D rendering. So I thought: "*Hei! What the hell! It should be easy to have a proper 3D X.org driver. Let's compile and install it!"*. This is exactly where problems started, with few documentation available on-line. Also, most of the time, what I found had a very high noise/value ratio. So finding the right hints to step forward was really difficult.
  In the end, the lack of official documentation, the lack of official support, the relatively small user-base and, on top of them, the intrinsic difficulties of clearly understanding how to properly interact with the hardware (aka: wireless network driver; ethernet network driver; graphic driver; boot process; etc. etc.) poses you in front of a decision: take it for what it provides out of the box or, viceversa, spend lots of time fine-tuning the gory detail. **This will be very different if you go with the real Raspberry PI way**, due to its much wider community (at least, I guess).

Some final notes:

- All what I wrote, relates to using GNU/LINUX on top of the hardware. If you rely on Android (BTW: the OrangePI came with Android built-in), probably you can  use it with a better user-experience;
- As for the difficulties described above, I strongly believe that those are the "price" you have to pay when you are an "early adopter", expecially if you are a F/OSS advocates (like me) ;-) . So it's not to be taken as a rant. It's exactly the opposite: a **wonderful** occasion to both increase free software adoption and, at the same time, learn lots and lots of interesting/technical things.

---

*P.S.: as of me, I still have to succed in compiling all the mali-software-stack to enable 3D graphic acceleration :-)*

Comment: Thanks Damiano.  I've never seen the orange pi before.  I like the sata controller build it.  I may give this a try first.   I'm only using this as a server without any gui.  Again thanks for your input